# On x axis I have double data time

Tags: r, datetime, plot, format

This is fragment of my dataset:

```
           Date         Open     Max Min Close Volumen
1   AGORA   19990420    49.9    49.9    46.1    47.1    214339
2   AGORA   19990421    47.0    47.2    46.5    46.7    160604
3   AGORA   19990422    47.0    49.9    47.0    49.1    155640
4   AGORA   19990423    49.4    51.0    49.1    49.7    164435
5   AGORA   19990426    49.5    49.8    49.0    49.0    90323
```

I want to make plot with Close (y axis) and Date (x axis). It's my code:

```
datawykres=strptime(Data, format="%Y%m%d")[3450:3569]
plot(y=dane,x=datawykres,type="l",main="Wykres indeksu AGORA",ylab="Wartość AGORA",xlab="Data")
axis(1, Data[c(T,rep(F,20))], F)  # interwał dat do ustalenia (teraz: co 20.)
text(x=datawykres[c(T,rep(F,20))], y=par("usr")[3]*.98, labels=datawykres[c(T,rep(F,20))], 
 xpd=T, srt=45, adj=c(1,0.5))
```

[image]

I want delete from x axis names of polish months like (lut, mar) and leave date like 2013-01-18. I don't have any idea, how I can do it. Anyone can help me ?

Thanks you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `xaxt="n"` to your plot call.

```
?par   # near the bottom of the parmeter descriptions.
```